# Phppgadmin, No objects found

Tags: php, postgresql, phppgadmin

I am trying to get my localhost db listed in phpPgAdmin, but it says No object found [phppgadmin GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElhMX.png)

I have already configured conf/config.inc

```
$conf['servers'][0]['desc'] = 'PostgreSQL'
$conf['servers'][0]['host'] = 'localhost';
$conf['servers'][0]['port'] = 5432;
$conf['owned_only'] = false;
```

Any help please, I have tried with Postgresql versions 9.2,9.5,10.3(not supported by phppgadmin?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EXPLANATION OF THE PROBLEM**

I see the problem! This error message is a bug in the phpPgAdmin code, which apparently has older code that was written *before* PHP 7.x was released.

The error in phpPgAdmin will appear if you've recently downloaded a technology stack with all of the latest versions of PHP, PostGreSQL and phpPgAdmin. For example... today's (Feb. 2019) latest versions are:

- PHP 7.3.1
- PostGreSQL version 11
- phpPgAdmin 5.6 (Nov. 12, 2018) <= This doesn't work with PHP 7.x, but we want it to work with it and we can make it work with it!

[PHP.net](http://www.php.net) explains the problem in their [Constructors and Destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) page:

> Warning Old style constructors are DEPRECATED in PHP 7.0, and will be
>   removed in a future version. You should always use __construct() in
>   new code.

Their example is in this section on that page:

> **Example #2 Constructors in namespaced classes**

```
<?php
namespace Foo;
class Bar {
    public function Bar() { <- This is an older style of creating a constructor.
        For PHP 7.x, it should be changed to "__construct" instead of "Bar".
        // treated as constructor in PHP 5.3.0-5.3.2
        // treated as regular method as of PHP 5.3.3
    }
}
?>
```

Now that we know what the problem is, here is how to solve it.

**SOLUTION**

Look in your `/phpPgAdmin/` folder on your web server. You should find the following files in the `/classes/` sub-folder:

- ArrayRecordSet.php <- Replace `function ArrayRecordSet` with `function __construct`
- class.select.php <- Replace `function XHtmlSimpleElement` with `function __construct`
- Gui.php <- Replace `function GUI` with `function __construct`
- Misc.php <- Replace `function Misc()` with `function __construct`
- Plugin.php <- Already has `function __construct`
- PluginManager.php <- Already has `function __construct`

Edit those files & change any of the constructor names - which appear as duplicate class names - to `__construct`.

When you save those files & reload phpPgAdmin in your browser, then you will see that the "No objects found" message will have disappeared. It will then display a server name.

**Voilà! The latest version of phpPgAdmin 5.6 works with the latest version of PHP 7.3.1 & the latest version of PostGreSQL 11!**

If you want to check the XML contents of that left tree, simply append this to your website as this is the rest of the URL, which it's using: `/phppgadmin/servers.php?action=tree`. That will help make debugging the phpPgAdmin code easier to do.

You can also remove the `action=tree` querystring parameter. Or search for it inside of the phpMyAdmin code.

**BUG REPORT**

I'll see about submitting a [phpPgAdmin bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/phppgadmin/bugs/) to with the link to this page. Hopefully, someone will fix this error in the phpPgAdmin code base.

Have fun using the latest version of phpPgAdmin, PHP & PostGreSQL!

Comment: Had to also do this in handful of places in \libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php

Comment: And also address the each() issue [https://sourceforge.net/p/phppgadmin/bugs/468/](https://sourceforge.net/p/phppgadmin/bugs/468/)

Comment: These changes have all been added to the latest release, which you can find at https://github.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin/releases/tag/REL_7-12-0